# Absolute TD inside TR with fixed table height makes the element appear below when there is scroll

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm making a menu that shows on table row hover like Gmail, and it works well when there is no fixed height on my `table` element, however, to meet my application needs this table must have a fixed height and HTML must have `overflow: hidden;`.

Here's an example: [CodePen example](https://codepen.io/mDEVnfe/pen/BajRyQK) (hover any row to toggle menu)

Remove `height="400px"` and `html { overflow: hidden; }` to see it working as expected.

When there is no scroll on the table, it works well, however, if you scroll down the table you'll see that the menu position appears below the line (more scroll = more below it appears). I know it's happening because the table has a fixed height, but there is any way to fix this with just CSS (or any javascript fix in last case)?

Any help will be wellcome.

Comment: Is this expected result? https://codepen.io/dgknca/pen/WNrjvvz

Comment: @dgknca as I said I need to keep the table height and overflow hidden on HTML.

Comment: sorry I edited can you check